# How do I call a method in a Master Page from a content's code-behind page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a public method in my ASP.NET Master Page. Is it possible to call this from a content page, and if so what are the steps/syntax?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From within the `Page` you can cast the `Master` page to a specific type (the type of your own `Master` that exposes the desired functionality), using `as` to side step any exceptions on type mismatches:

```
var master = Master as MyMasterPage;
if (master != null)
{
    master.Method();
}
```

In the above code, if `Master` is not of type `MyMasterPage` then `master` will be `null` and no method call will be attempted; otherwise it will be called as expected.

Comment: Check out Uwe Keim's answer first; I found it very simple to use.

Answer (score 18):

Use the [`MasterType` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) like e.g.:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/masters/SourcePage.master" %>
```

Then you can use the method like this:

```
Master.Method();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply do like...

```
MasterPageClassName MasterPage = (MasterPageClassName)Page.Master;
MasterPage.MasterMethod();
```

Check for Details [ACCESS A METHOD IN A MASTER PAGE WITH CODE-BEHIND](http://www.braintrove.com/article/17)

Comment: Can you add this as a static member at the top of your page?

Answer (score 6):

```
MyMasterPageType master = (MyMasterPageType)this.Master;
master.MasterPageMethod();
```

Comment: Can you add this as a static member at the top of your page?

Comment: Not a static member, because the master page is specific to the page currently handling the request. You could make an instance property for the master page though: `private MyMasterPageType master { get { return (MyMasterPageType)this.Master; } }`