# Master Page and Child Page Events

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, master-pages

I have a Master Page which contains a Dropdown, based on the Drop down selection I change the language of the entire site. Now, in one of the child pages I am using a repeater and binding some data to it. I am also using the ItemDataBound event of the repeater as well (I require a tooltip for one of the cells). I am trying to figure out a way when the master page Dropdown value is changed I should also fire the ItemDataBound event so that the data is displayed in the correct language. I am guessing it has to do something with playing around certain events. Any ideas or feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ItemDataBound is only fired when data is bound to the control. You would have to rebind the data to the repeater in order for its ItemDataBound events to fire again.

Your other option is to write additional code to loop through all of the items in your repeater and perform the actions you usually perform in ItemDataBound.

Comment: I did think of the same as well, but in which event would I write the code similar to the ItemBound Event? As the Dropdown is in the Master Page and the Repeater is in the Child Page I am wondering how to proceed with this issue.

Comment: Based on the little bit I know about your project I could recommend using a session variable to store the current language settings for your site. Also, maybe this page could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165930/how-to-call-content-page-function-from-master-page