# Find and Call Sub from Master.vb in ASP VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, function, cookies, find

I need to find and call the Sub below which in my Master.vb from a separate file (About.vb). The reason I need to do this is I'm showing a count of some values in a cookie on every page but need to change the cookie values and count in the About.aspx.vb file. I always fall one number behind when the master Sub checks the cookie as it's changed after the Master loads.

Below is the Sub I need to call from About.aspx.vb:

```
Sub FavSideTab()
    If Request.Cookies("Favourites") IsNot Nothing Then

        Dim FavCookieVal As String = Request.Cookies("Favourites").Value

        FavouritesSideTab.Visible = True
        Dim cnt As Integer = FavCookieVal.Count(Function(ch) ch = ","c)
        FavouritesCount.Text = cnt
    Else
        FavouritesSideTab.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Method in Master Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332889/call-method-in-master-page)

Comment: You could change event instead. Change the cookie on the OnInit and set the layout on the load or prerender

Answer (score 0):

In your masterpage use this code

```
Public Sub FavSideTab()
  If Request.Cookies("Favourites") IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim FavCookieVal As String = Request.Cookies("Favourites").Value
    FavouritesSideTab.Visible = True
    Dim cnt As Integer = FavCookieVal.Count(Function(ch) ch = ","c)
    FavouritesCount.Text = cnt
  Else
    FavouritesSideTab.Visible = False
  End If
End Sub
```

In your CONTENT pages (code blocks) use this code...

```
Me.Master.FavSideTab
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the code below to just edit the literal in the master page from the content page rather than run the function in the master page.

```
 CType(Master.FindControl("FavouritesCount"), Literal).Text = cnt
```