# Creating a master page in ASP.NET error on markup aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I tried creating a **master page** in ASP.NET

I have this error on the **Markup** of page **sDefault.aspx** where I need call the **master page** :

```
CS0103: The name 'Base64ForUrlEncode' does not exist in the current context.
```

Why I have this error ?
In the **MasterPage.master.cs** I have insert the :

```
public static string Base64ForUrlEncode(string str)
{
    byte[] encbuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(encbuff);
}
```

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332889/call-method-in-master-page) without success .

How to do resolve this?
My code below.

This is the code of **MasterPage.master.cs**

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            InitializeCulture();
        }
    }

    protected void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Page.Culture = "en-US";
        Page.UICulture = "en-US";
    }    

    public static string Base64ForUrlEncode(string str)
    {
        byte[] encbuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
        return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(encbuff);
    }

    public static string Base64ForUrlDecode(string str)
    {
        byte[] decbuff = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(str);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decbuff);
    }    
}
```

This is the code of **MasterPage.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <style type="text/css">

        .labelStyle {
            color: red;
            background-color: yellow;
            border: Solid 2px Red;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 30em;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .image {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .toUpper {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .header {
            background-color: #686565;
            font: bold;
            color: #686565;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this the **Markup** of page **sDefault.aspx** where I need call the master page :

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="sDefault.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="sDefault" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" %>
    <%@ MasterType  virtualPath="MasterPage.master"%>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  EmptyDataText="No data" 
                  EnableViewState="true"
                  runat="server" 
                  DataKeyNames="sID" 
                  HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrows" />
                    <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField 
                                 HeaderText="Nr" 
                                 ItemStyle-CssClass="ddl_Class_new" 
                                 ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server"
                                        NavigateUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Nr").ToString()) ? "" : 
                      Eval("Nr").ToString().Equals("0") ? "" : 
                      String.Format("sExport1.aspx?d={0}&s={1}",
Base64ForUrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("d").ToString())),
   HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Base64ForUrlEncode("s")))) %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Content>
```

**Edit #1**

*Code-Behind Default.asp.cs*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MasterPage MasterPage = (MasterPage)Page.Master;
        MasterPage.Base64ForUrlEncode(null);
    }
}
```

**Edit #2**

*Code-Behind Default.asp.cs*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MasterPage mp = (MasterPage)Page.Master;
        string test = mp.Base64ForUrlEncode("TestUrl");
    }
}
```

*Markup aspx*

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# mp.Base64ForUrlEncode("TestUrl") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

*MasterPage.master.cs*

```
public string Base64ForUrlEncode(string str)
{
    byte[] encbuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(encbuff);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Method in Master Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332889/call-method-in-master-page)

Answer (score 0):

`Base64ForUrlEncode` is in the Master page class (`public partial class MasterPage`), while the aspx page `sDefault` has it's own. Therefore the method cannot be found unless you specify the namespace on the aspx.

```
<%= YourNameSpace.MasterPage.Base64ForUrlEncode("test")  %>
```

Update

```
public MasterPage master;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    master = (MasterPage)Page.Master;
    string s = master.Base64ForUrlEncode("test");
}
```

Then make the `Base64ForUrlEncode` method in the Master Public an non-static

```
public string Base64ForUrlEncode(string str)
{
}
```

Now you can reference it directly on the aspx

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# master.Base64ForUrlEncode("TestUrl") %>                   
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks but I have error **Only content controls are allowed directly on a content page that contains content checks.**

Comment: Use `<%#` inside another control, like a GridView.

Comment: Please see my **Edit #1** in my first question. I have the same error.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank, now the error is : CS0176: member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead MasterPage.Base64ForUrlEncode (string)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to reference to your edit 1:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MasterPage MasterPage = (MasterPage)Page.Master;
        MasterPage.Base64ForUrlEncode(null);
    }
}
```

change it to:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MasterPage mp = (MasterPage)Page.Master;
        string test = mp.Base64ForUrlEncode("your test string");
    }
}
```

You could change the grid to a repeater if you have just 1 field and/or reference a function in the code behind to build the url.

This is too much logic in the view imho:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server"
               NavigateUrl='<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Nr").ToString()) ? "" : 
                  Eval("Nr").ToString().Equals("0") ? "" : 
                  String.Format("sExport1.aspx?d={0}&s={1}",
Base64ForUrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("d").ToString())),
   HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Base64ForUrlEncode("s")))) %>' />
```

(or something "on item data bound")

Comment: Thank, now the error is : CS0176: member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead MasterPage.Base64ForUrlEncode (string)

Comment: How did you refactor your **TemplateField / ItemTemplate**?

Comment: Please see my **Edit #2** in my first question. I have the same error.